# Multindexing in Pandas results in exception

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am going through the examples of the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html ) and when I run the following code I get an exception I do not understand and do not know how to handle:

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
            np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
df.xs(('one', 'bar'), level=('second', 'first'), axis=1)

AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'get_loc_level'
```

Moreover:

```
df.MultiIndex.get_loc_level(key = 'First', level = 0)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'MultiIndex'

df.loc[xs[:, ['one']], :]
NameError: name 'xs' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `axis=0` for select `MultiIndex` in index with levels by positions, because not defined index names:

```
a = df.xs(('one', 'bar'), level=[1,0], axis=0)
print (a)
                0         1         2        3
bar one  0.010867 -1.033593 -0.275599 -0.59924
```

If define index names:

```
df.index.names = ['first','second']
a = df.xs(('one', 'bar'), level=('second', 'first'), axis=0)
print (a)
                     0         1         2         3
first second                                        
bar   one     0.525222 -0.486259  0.477893  0.623223
```